# Как правильно трактовать данные предложения?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Пример:

> Машина административного здания белого цвета.

Как правильно трактуется?

1) Машина **белого цвета**, принадлежащая административному зданию.

2) Машина, принадлежащая административному зданию **белого цвета**.

Ещё пример предложения:

> Машина посольства 2006 года.

Трактовать можно в два смысла?

1) Машина 2006 года выпуска, принадлежащая посольству.

2) Машина, принадлежащая посольству 2006 года постройки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае белое, надо полагать, административное здание. Во-первых, потому, что по тексту они неразрывны. Во-вторых, если бы речь шла о белой машине, гораздо естественней было бы написать ***белая машина административного здания***.

Во втором предложении 2006 года, конечно же, машина. Иначе это было бы не предложением, а словосочетанием: "Машина посольства, построенного в 2006 году..." Сказуемого-то нету.